# For loop with maximum text fields

Tags: php

I want to print a text field 6 times, however if all of them are filled then the loop should not continue. Here's my code:

```
 <fieldset class="keywords">
  <?php
    $fkeywords = get_the_terms($pid, 'fkeywords');
    if (is_array($fkeywords)) {
      foreach ($fkeywords as $keyword) {
       echo '<input type="text" name="fkeywords[]" id="'.$keyword->slug.'" value="'.$keyword->slug.'">';
      }
    }
  ?>
 <ol>
<?php for ($i=0; $i<6; $i++ ){ ?>
    <li><input type="text" size="20" name="foodir_keywords[]" /></li>
<?php } ?>
 </ol>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: what do you mean by if all of them are filled ?

Comment: Are you assigning any value to these input fields?

Comment: you mean if text fields value is already filled,  loop should not continue ?

Comment: i have updated the code, here's a screenshot what i mean to say: http://i.imgur.com/ShJKhf3.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow figured it out myself:

```
$keyCount = count($fkeywords);
for ($i=0; $i<6-$keyCount; $i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

For HTML:

```
<input type="text" size="20" name="keywords[]" id="valueCheck" />
```

You can use this function for checking purpose:

```
function checkInput() { 
    var valueCheck = document.getElementById('valueCheck').value; 
    if(!valueCheck.match(/\S/)) {
        alert ('EMPTY');
        return false;
    } else {
        alert("Filled");
        return true;
    }
}
```